# Achieve inheritance using object literal in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, object-literal

How do i achieve this :

```
function Vehicle(){
    this.mobility = true;
};
function Car(){};
Car.prototype = new Vehicle();
var myCar = new Car();
console.log(myCar.mobility);
```

Using objects created with Object literals ?

I know about Object.create() but is there any way like

```
Car.prototype = new Vehicle();
```

to achieve that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you do it using `__proto__`:

```
var propertiesToInherit = { 'horsepower': 201, 'make': 'Acura' }
var myCar = {};
myCar.__proto__ = propertiesToInherit;

console.log(myCar.horsepower); // 201
console.log(myCar.make); // Acura
```

That being said, I would avoid doing this. It looks like it is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Proto)

Comment: Hmmm, ya i thought of it. But unfortunately it's deprecated as you said.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `Object.create`? Or standard functional inheritance?

Comment: No, but i have read somewhere that `Object.create()` is an ECMAScript5 feature so i'm worried about cross-browser compatibility. I'm trying to know an alternative to it, in case i had to use object literals not constructors  .

Comment: `Object.create` is the way to go. But you are correct, it is not [implemented everywhere](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/). Your best bet is to create a [polyfill](http://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill/)

Comment: The mozilla website is a GREAT resource for polyfills.   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be [Prototype.js](http://www.prototypejs.org/); among other things, it allows you to create and extend JS classes using a cleaner syntax:

```
// properties are directly passed to `create` method
var Person = Class.create({
  initialize: function(name) {
    this.name = name;
  },
  say: function(message) {
    return this.name + ': ' + message;
  }
});

// when subclassing, specify the class you want to inherit from
var Pirate = Class.create(Person, {
  // redefine the speak method
  say: function($super, message) {
    return $super(message) + ', yarr!';
  }
});

var john = new Pirate('Long John');
john.say('ahoy matey');
// -> "Long John: ahoy matey, yarr!"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly, but maybe you could try this:

```
var literal = { mobility: true };
function Car(){};
Car.prototype = literal;
var myCar = new Car();
console.log(myCar.mobility);
```

Note that if you change the literal, you change all instances of `Car` that were created.

Comment: Ya, but can it be achieved without making the `Car` constructor. I mean directly from `myCar` object.

Comment: You mean `var myCar = literal;`? Or maybe you want to copy literal's contents into car?

Comment: I mean can we inherit `myCar` from `literal` directly, or somehow other than creating `Car` constructor, then `Car.prototype = literal` and instantiating `myCar` from it? I mean can we create `myCar` using object literal and then inheriting it from the object `literal` ?

Comment: Thanks anyways for being patient with me :)